# Referencing SD card from Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel

I am writing an Android app on the Jetpack Composable platform with Android Studio. I need to read and write files on an SD card that is installed in the tablet. I can define the path to the card as follows:

```
private val externalStorageVolumes = context.let { ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(it.applicationContext, null) }

private val sdCardStorage = externalStorageVolumes[1]
```

The problem is: I want to access the card from a view's ViewModel, but as you can see I need to pass a reference to a context. Apparently one should not refence any context from a ViewModel, as that can lead to memory leaks.

Is the any way to read and write to a SD card from a ViewModel that does not need a context? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Apparently one should not refence any context from a ViewModel, as that can lead to memory leaks

That is what [`AndroidViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/AndroidViewModel) is for. It mediates access to the `Application`, which is a singleton `Context` safe to use from a `ViewModel`.

Even better is to have your data storage logic be managed by a singleton repository class, as part of [a layered architecture](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture#data-layer). You would have the repository get access to the `Application` singleton via dependency inversion (Dagger/Hilt, Koin, etc.).

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be what I am looking for!